# Laravel: Making links invisible to guests

Tags: php, laravel

I am using L3 to make a site such that guests can leave comments without need to log in then there will be an admin login. I have a menu bar used for navigation by both the guests and admin but on admin login, the menu bar should have more options. On my layout, this is what i have;

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse" id="main-menu">
            <ul class="nav" id="main-menu-left">

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Contact Us<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="swatch-menu">
                        <li>{{HTML::link('posts/contact','Leave a coment')}}</li>
                        <li>{{HTML::link('posts/location','Grt Our Locations')}}</li>
                        @if (Session::has('permission'))
                        <li>{{HTML::link('posts/review','Review Posts')}}</li>                            
                        <li>{{HTML::link('posts/list','List all Posts')}}</li>
                        @endif
                    </ul>
</div>
```

On my admin controller, i created a Session so as to make posts/review and posts/list accessible to admin only. This is what i have

```
public function post_login()
{
    $email = Input::get('email');
    $password = Input::get('password');


    $credentials = array
        ('username' => $email,
        'password' => $password);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials))
    {
        Session::put('permission', 'admin');
        return Redirect::to('admin/index');
    } else
    {
        Session::flash('status_error', 'Your email or password is invalid - please try again.');
        return Redirect::to('admin/login');
    }
}
```

This is working OK except for the fact that Guests can see the admin links when they hover their mouse over the menu bar (i.e they can see 'Review Posts' and 'List all Post'. They cannot access the pages though (they are redirected to admin login page). My question is, how do i make these links invisible to guests but visible to admin on login? Both guest and admin have to use same layout. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Put conditional upon whether user is admin or not and then output the link according to it. A simple `if` will do.

Comment: itachi, do you mind giving me a code example? I would highly appreciate.

Comment: By the way: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46607/laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the following approach instead of Session:

```php
@if (Auth::user())
    <a href="#">Admin</a>
@endif
```

Comment: By the way, you can also use `if (Auth::guest())` to show login button only for users logged out :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have already signed in once and then sign out again to test the site. It looks like you didn't clear the "permission" session on sign out.

Comment: Could you please guide me on how to clear permission on sign out?

Comment: i have used 
    Session::forget('permission');
on my log out function but it is still not working.

Comment: This weird. I setup a test repo on Laravel 3.2.14 but I couldn't replicate your problem. I'm able to hide those admin-level links after logout. Below is my logout code: `Auth::logout();

 Session::forget('permission');` Check your database if the permission is still available after logout.